# Why: $[T^*]_{\beta} = [T]^*_{\beta}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $T$ is a linear operator on finite-dimensional inner product space $V$. Let $\beta$ be an orthonormal basis for $V$, then what is the reasoning behind the property that  $[T^*]_{\beta} = [T]^*_{\beta}$?

Comment: What does $[T^*]_\beta$ mean?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: this is the matrix corresponding to the operator $T^{*}$ where $\beta$ is the orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n$ be the element of $\beta$. If $[T]_\beta=(a_{ij})_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n}$, then$$(\forall i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}):Te_i=\sum_{j=1}^na_{ji}e_j.$$Therefore$$(\forall i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}):\langle Te_i,e_j\rangle=a_{ji}.$$But then$$(\forall i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}):\langle e_i,T^*e_j\rangle=a_{ji},$$which means that$$(\forall i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}):\langle T^*e_i,e_j\rangle=a_{ij}.$$In other words,$$(\forall i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}):T^*e_i=\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}e_j,$$which is equivalent to the assertion $[T^*]_\beta=[T]_\beta^*$, since $[T]_\beta^*=(a_{ji})_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\beta=\{v_1, ...,v_{n}\}$ be the orthonormal basis for $V$. If we suppose $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$ be the element in $i$-th row and $j$-th column of $[T]_{\beta}$ and $[T^{*}]_{\beta}$, then we have for all $i,j$,

$$a^{*}_{ij} = \overline{a_{ji}} = \overline{\langle Tv_{i},v_{j}  \rangle} = \overline{\langle v_{i},T^{*}v_{j}  \rangle} = \langle T^{*}v_{j},v_{i}  \rangle = b_{ij} \implies [T^{*}]_{\beta}={[T]}^{*}_{\beta},$$

Here, we have used the fact that $T(v_{i})=\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ji}v_{j}$.